# Execution gets stopped in ssh remote server

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, executable, execute-command

I am trying to run Quantum ESPRESSO on a remote server through SSH in the Linux terminal from my machine.

For this, I am running a binary executable program with a text input file as:

```
$ mpirun -np 20 pw.x < input.in > output.out
```

The program is executing successfully but getting stopped at some point in time (after 2 hours) and does not write results to the output file.

What can I do to execute the program again from where it has stopped as I don't want to run it from scratch (since it consumes a lot of time)?

What could be the reason for stopping?

How can I execute it again.

Please help. I am running out of clues with this.

Thanking you!

Comment: Is your SSH connection getting terminated by the remote host / your machine at some point? This is usually the default behavior of SSH servers as a security policy (maximum idle time). Poor network connectivity may also cause the connection to be closed. When your SSH connection is closed it is equal to a user logging out, thus causing all of the processes started by it to terminate.

Comment: @Pizza yes, the SSH connection is getting terminated by default. But shouldn't the program executed by me have to run on the server without any termination? Isn't it the case?

Comment: If you started the program using the SSH connection, it'll get terminated once the connection goes off (or the command exit was typed). You could test it by increasing / decreasing your SSH session maximum time (and maximum idle time), or by terminating the connection manually by typing exit or closing the console.

Comment: If you discover that this was the cause of this problem, let me know in the comments so I'll turn them into an answer with a solution added (of how to keep the process alive even after closing the connection). This would really help future users facing similar situations find a solution more quickly.

Comment: @Pizza yes, please provide an answer on how to keep the process still alive even after log out of the system. It has taken a lot of time to start the process again and again. I am using bash.sh to execute the process. Thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on the comments section:**
Your script is most likely to be terminated by the remote OS when the SSH connection is closed, either by the remote server or by the local machine.

**Why does the remote machine close the connection?**

This is the default security configuration for SSH servers - closing a session when the maximum allowed session time is reached, or the maximum allowed idle time is reached.

**Why are processes started by the remote user are terminated once logged out?**

The answer is even more simple than security reasons: ssh logout is almost equivalent to a local user logging out of their system, thus terminating all of the the processes started by them. The system sends a [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) to each process - a [signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) that causes them to begin a termination procedure.

**How to avoid this process termination after ssh logout?**

Once connected to the remote machine using SSH, we can simply run a command / script using [nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) to ignore this signal when logging out:

```
nohup <script_or_program> &
```

In your case:

```
nohup mpirun -np 20 pw.x < input.in > output.out &
```

Each process we want to persist after logout has to be started using `nohup`.

**Important note about nohup:**

Unless our process terminates by itself, from this point if we want to terminate it manually (either by remote or local connection), we'll have to manually send a SIGKILL signal to the process using the `kill` command:
`kill -9 <process_id>`

Comment: Thanking you for your kind answer! Really helpful!

Comment: However, I am receiving the following message in the terminal: "nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout" but the program is running successfully. Can I close the terminal now without worrying about job termination?

Comment: Yes this is normal. Also, your terminal might appear as if it is trying to execute something, yet it is a cosmetic side effect of the terminal when moving a program to the background. if you press the enter key a new terminal line will appear, allowing you to continue using it normally. It is also best practice to type `exit` so the SSH connection closes properly, rather closing the terminal itself.